# A453 Task 3 Programming

Tags: python, coding-style, computer-science

I am currently studying computer science as a GCSE student. Me and my teacher are struggling with task 3. The requirements of the task are: 
It then needs to ask the user what class they would like to view
After this it will need to ask if they would like to view the file sorted    alphabetically, the high scores of the particular class or if they would like to view the average of each student in the selected class

```
import csv  
print("1 for Class A\n2 for Class B\n3 for Class C")  
choosen=int(input())  
class_a = open('class_a.csv')  
class_b = open('class_b.txt')  
class_c = open('class_c.txt')  
if choosen == 1:  
 print("1 for for alphabetical orderwith each students highest score\n2 for highest score, highest to lowest\n3 for average score, highest to lowest")  
    cho_two=int(input())  
    csv_a = csv.reader(class_a)  
    a_list = []  
    for row in csv_a:  
        row[1] = int(row[1])  
        row[2] = int(row[2])  
        row[3] = int(row[4])  
        minimum = min(row[1:2])  
        row.append(minimum)  
        maximum = max(row[1:2])  
        row.append(maximum)  
        average = sum(row[1:2])//3  
        row.append(average)  
        a_list.append(row[0:9])  
    if cho_two == 1:  
        alphabetical = [[x[0],x[6]] for x in a_list]  
        print("\nCLASS A\nEach students highest by alphabetical order \n")  
        for alpha_order in sorted(alphabetical):  
            print(alpha_order)  
            class_a.close()  
    elif cho_two == 2:  
        print("\nCLASS A\nThe highest score to the lowest \n")  
        for high_scr in sorted(highest_score,reverse = True):  
            print(high_scr)  
            class_a.close()             
    elif cho_two == 3:  
        average_score = [[x[8],x[0]] for x in a_list]  
        print("\nCLASS A\nThe average score from highest to lowest \n")  
        for ave_scr in sorted(average_score,reverse = True):  
            print(ave_scr)  
            class_a.close()
```

My code when run in python tells me there is a problem on line 13 with "index out of range"

My text file contains:
Roo,2,3,
Roo,4,4,
Alfie,5,8,
Alfie,2,8,
Bob,2,8,
Connor,3,5,
Connor,5,3,
Ellis,5,6,
George,5,4,
Ellis,4,9,
Nathan,5,6,
George,5,5,
Alfie,9,4,
George,4,7,
Celis,4,5,
Leo,3,2,
Celis,6,1,
Leo,5,2,

When I run the program the code, row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVIdz.png) = into(row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVIdz.png)) tells me it's out of range? Any solutions?

Comment: It would help if you could copy & paste your code into your answer, rather than adding an image of it.

Comment: Please dont post a screen capture of your code editor - code is text, and text can be posted here (if not too long - but if it's too long you should instead post a simplified example that reproduces the issue).

Comment: I'm trying to help from school myself and the image is filtered, add it as text please :)

Comment: Welcome :) I recommend pasting your code where others can copy it, eg, GitHub Gists. Also, is there something missing at the end of the 2nd sentence? Last thing: remember that Python is zero-indexed, so the first item in a sequence is indexed 0.

Comment: my code is now in the question for anyone wishing to help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python - like most programming languages - uses zero-based indexing, which means the first element of a sequence is at index 0 and the last one at index `len(sequence) - 1`.

In your code you have rows with three elements each, and you are trying to access `row[3]`, which would be the index of an (inexistant) fourth element, hence your error.

Also if your teacher is "struggling" with such a basic problem, you should probably find a competent teacher instead.

Comment: You took the words right out of my keyboard.

Comment: Ditto. Hogging all the rep :D

Comment: that's my problem. non of my teachers are competent of fixing this